# How do I remove south from a django project

Tags: python, django, django-south

I installed south and tried a few changes using it, which didn't exactly work out the way I wanted it to. Thankfully, my data is safe but locked into south. I want to remove south and use syncdb normally now, how do I do that without affecting my data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove `'south'` from INSTALLED_APPS, remove `south_migrations` table from DB.

Comment: I'm a noob to postgres and dbs. I wasn't sure if it would remove the `south_migrationhistory_id_seq` sequence when I dropped the table by running `DROP TABLE south_migrationhistory;`. It does remove the table and the sequence.

Comment: It did right thing. ``south_migrationhistory_id_seq`` has no sense without ``south_migrationhistory`` table.

Answer (score 5):

> Remove 'south' from INSTALLED_APPS, remove south_migrations table from
>   DB.

Also, you'll need to delete the Migrations folders from your app folders.

Answer (score 3):

What does it mean for your data to be "locked into" South? The data lives in the database, and South simply creates the schema for you and migrates it when necessary. If you remove South, the data will stay exactly the same.

Comment: I meant syncdb doesn't work in the normal way. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

project is already in development then follow below steps.

1>You have to remove 'south' from installed apps

2>Delete all migrations from migrations folder

3> Delete south_migrations table from database

After following above steps, Suppose you want to vanish south completely from your system then follow below commands.

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python-django-south
```

Above command will uninstall south with it's all dependencies.
And to know more about the uninstalling south..click this [link](http://www.installion.co.uk/ubuntu/saucy/main/p/python-django-south/en/uninstall/index.html)